# How to fade in text without using setInterval? Is there a CSS way to do this?

Tags: javascript, css, opacity, fade, setinterval

I want to make some text fade in. I've done such things using Javascript and setInterval. That works but it seems like too much gunk for such a simple effect.

Is there a CSS way to do a text fade in? For instance, it starts as 0% opacity and becomes 100% opaque over a time frame that I specify.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes... with css and maybe a line of javascript, but it will need to be css3 and thus won't support older browsers.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it on `:hover` with CSS3 transformations. A very simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/xaBgQ/

Comment: Interesting but this isn't for hovering. I want the text to appear gradually when the page first appears and then remain visible.

Comment: Yea, the CSS3 transitions can only occur on CSS-targetable events, like :hover, :active:, :focus, etc. Javascript is the only way for what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Not purely with CSS (across all browsers), jQuery provide a nice API for such effects, the [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) method will probably be a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 transitions support this, but support is currently a bit spotty.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your can user the CSS3 transition timing functions.

Have a look here for some examples:

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/timing-function/

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas that come to mind:

1) An animation framework like jQuery, YUI, etc.  Sure, those probably use setInterval internally but then it's their gunk and not yours.

2) CSS3 - If you only need to work on the latest browsers or have a fall back plan, this might be a good way to go.  Plenty of examples if you [Google for "CSS3 animation"](http://www.google.com/search?q=CSS3%20animation)

3) If your text is static and small, perhaps an animated GIF instead.

Hope this helps!